# How to catch the colorbox opening event using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, drupal, colorbox

I have a very-very basic knowledge of jQuery but I need to solve this issue: I have a Drupal-based webpage and I've created a map that opens in Colorbox (with the help of [Colorbox Node](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox_node) module). So there is a hyperlink on a page: `<a class="colorbox-node init-colorbox-node-processed-processed" href="/places_fullscreen">Open in fullscreen</a>`. Clicking on it a `<div>` with `#colorbox` css-selector will be visible in the Colorbox-overlay.
First of all I'd like to catch the event when the colorbox is opened and then doing something.

I've browsed the internet for solutions and tried to implement them without any success.

First suggestion:

```
(function($) {
    $(".colorbox-node").colorbox( {
    onComplete: function() {
        console.log('ColorBox is currently open');
    }
    });
})
```

Second suggestion:

```
(function($) {
    if ($("#colorbox").css("display")=="block") {
        console.log('ColorBox is currently open');
    }
})
```

What would be the proper solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've learnt that I should have used the Drupal behaviors. So the following code does the trick:

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.whateverName= {
        attach: function (context, settings) {
            if ($('#colorbox').css('display') == 'block') {
               console.log('ColorBox is currently open');
            }
        }
    };
}) (jQuery);
```